# Radioactivity formula using differential equations?

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations

After $12$ days, a $40$ gram substance decays to $9.3$ grams. If the decay rate is proportional to the amount of substance left, how much of the substance will be left after $37$ days?

I solved it using the formula $y=ce^{-kt}$. I used $-k$ instead of $k$ because it is a decay function. I found $k$ by plugging in $(12, 9.3)$, then used that $k$ to find $y$ when $t = 37$. For -k, I got -ln(9.3/40), and so the equation would be y=40e^(-37(ln(9.3/40)/12)). However I got $89$ for y, which was incorrect, so can someone please point out where I made a mistake? Thank you in advance!

Comment: What was your answer, and how exactly did you work out the answer? Your method is correct, but we need more information for us to help you.

Comment: I edited your question, but in the future, you should format your posts with [Mathjax](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation)

Comment: You seem to have got the right idea, which means it's a calculation error of some sort. The working involves taking a natural logarithm. Did you do it right? The only way we can tell is if you show your working in full.

Comment: You need to substitute $12$ for $t$ when you make your initial determination of $k$.  You should have gotten $k=-\frac1{12}\log\frac{9.3}{40}$

Comment: @Mitali Mittal, would you like to accept the answer? :-)

Answer (score 1):

There is some confusion with that negative sign in the exponent.

If you are using $-k$ as the coefficient in the exponent, then you are expecting $k$ itself to be positive. You say you found $-k$ to be $-\ln(9.3/40)$, which would mean $k$ was $\ln(9.3/40)$. But $\ln(9.3/40)$ is negative, despite the lack of a negative sign in that expression. Really, $-k=\ln(9.3/40)$, so where you wrote
$$y=40e^{-37(\ln(9.3/40)/12)}$$
it should be
$$y=40e^{37(\ln(9.3/40)/12)}\approx0.445$$

---

Also you say you got $89$ for $y$. This is (very close to) what I get if I put that negative sign back in and omit the $40$ at the front, so two issues:
$$e^{-37(\ln(9.3/40)/12)}\approx89.85$$
Maybe this is what happened. Maybe with a little rounding error too.

Answer (score 0):

$$y=ce^{-kt}$$
The constant $k$ is not correct:
$$ 9.3=40e^{-12k}$$
$$k=-\dfrac 1 {12}\ln \left( \dfrac  {9.3}{40} \right)$$
So that you have:
$$y=40e^{-37k}$$
$$y=40e^{\dfrac {37} {12}\ln \left( \dfrac  {9.3}{40} \right)}$$
$$y=40\left( \dfrac  {9.3}{40} \right)^{\dfrac {37} {12}}$$

Answer (score 0):

$$y=40(e^{-kt})\\ 
k=\frac{1}{12}\ln\left(\frac{40}{9.3}\right)\\ 
(y) _{t=37}=40(e^{-\frac{1}{12}\ln\left(\frac{40}{9.3}\right) 37})\\ 
y=40\left(\frac{9.3}{40}\right) ^{\frac{37}{12}}$$

My calculations give $y=0.445$.

Comment: @alex.jordan, you're correct. My mistake... I forgot to multiply by $40$.